# ASP.Net MVC 3 DataAnnotations validating List<T>

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations, generic-list

I have a ViewModel that has been deserialized from JSON which looks something like this:

```
public class UserThingsUpdateViewModel
{
    public IList<Thing> Things { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

`Thing` is also a ViewModel which also has various DataAnnotaion ValidationAttribute attributes on the properties.

The problem is that Lists don't seem to get validated and even after a through search I cant seem to find any articles that tackle this. Most suggest that the ViewModel is wrong if it includes a list.

So, what is the best way to validate my list and add Model Errors to the Model State?

Answer (score 2):

Prior to checking `ModelState.IsValid`, you could add code to step through and validate each `Thing`, as follows:

```
foreach (var thing in Things)
    TryValidateModel(thing);
```

This will validate each item, and add any errors to ModelState.

Comment: thanks, that's what I had as a plan b! I was hoping there was a more elegant solution

Comment: Dve, I must agree, an elegant solution this is not.  But sometimes, I don't want to beat my head against the wall trying to reach the elegant solution ... sometimes.

Comment: haha wise words, I think I will have to admit defeat.. for now

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom validator attribute and decorate the list property with it? That would allow you to write custom logic to get the elements out of the list and validate them.

Comment: More info on custom validation attributes - http://www.squarewidget.com/post/2011/06/Simple-and-Custom-Validation-in-MVC-3.aspx

Comment: But how would you invoke the model validation?.. the model has already been bound.